# Bootstrap affix reset an affixed element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a sidebar and this is my code :

### HTML

```
<section class="mySection">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <header class="col-md-12">
                <h3>Heading</h3>
                <p><em>Some text</em></p>
            </header>

            <!--Main Content Container - Make full width on smaller devices-->
            <article class="col-md-9 col-sm-12" role="main">
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
                <p>Text to enable scrolling</p>
            </article>
            <!--Sidebar - Hide on Small and extra small devices-->
            <aside class="col-md-3 hidden-sm hidden-xs" role="complementary" data-spy="affix">
                <section class="card">
                    <header>
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                    </header>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </section>
                <section class="card">
                    <header>
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                    </header>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                </section>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

### CSS

```
aside.affix {
    top: 0;
}
```

### JQuery

```
var $scrollHeight = $ ( '#main-nav').outerHeight ( true );

$ ( 'aside' ).affix ({
    offset: { top: $scrollHeight }
});

$ ( 'aside' ).one ( 'affix.bs.affix', function (  ) {
    /**Get sidebar's offset position**/
    var $offset = $ ( 'aside' ).offset (  );

    /**Get sidebar's width**/
    var $width = $ ( 'aside' ).outerWidth ( true );

    /**Create an style array for our sidebar**/
    var styles = {
        left : $offset.left,
        width: $width
    };

    /**Set aside/Sidebar's CSS.**/
    $ ( 'aside' ).css ( styles );
});
```

Everything is working fine except when I scroll the page back all the way to the top, the aside/my sidebar vanishes from the scene. **How do I fix this ?**

**Bootplay:**
http://www.bootply.com/FjJlykT5e5

Comment: Can you create a fiddle please. That would help

Comment: @RehbanKhatri I have added the bootplay link, please have a look.

Comment: It's not hidden, It just moves to the extreme right for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the affix element returns to it's original state it's position is not returning back to the original. All that is needed is to handle the Bootstrap affix event `affix-top.bs.affix` which is fired right before the affix element returns to it's original state and the class changes from `.affix` to `.affix-top` in the even handler simply remove the inline `style` attribute.

```
$ ( 'aside' ).on ( 'affix-top.bs.affix', function ( event ) {
    /**Remove inline style attributes from the element**/
    $ ( this ).removeAttr ( 'style' );
} );
```